# ReactJS onClick without JSX

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and trying to set the onClick property of a react component but get the following error:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: <ul />. Did you accidentally export a JSX literal instead of a component?
```

My code is currently as follows:

```
// Navbar Component
class Navbar extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.onItemClick = this.onItemClick.bind(this);
  };

  onItemClick () {
    console.log('Test');
  }

  render() {
    const home = React.createElement('li', {className: 'navbar-item', id: 'home'}, 'Home');
    const contact = React.createElement('li', {className: 'navbar-item', id: 'about'}, 'Contact');
    const about = React.createElement('li', {className: 'navbar-item', id: 'contact', onClick: this.onItemClick()}, 'About');

    return React.createElement('ul', {className: 'navbar'}, about, contact, home);
  }

}

var testbar = new Navbar;
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(testbar.render(), null, null),
  document.getElementById('navbar')
);
```

Any tips on getting the onclick function to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to pass your class to `ReactDOM.render` method and let it handle the instance generation and rendering.

Also, you were calling your `onItemClick` method instead of passing it to the onClick event listener.

```js
// Navbar Component
class Navbar extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onItemClick = this.onItemClick.bind(this);
  };

  onItemClick() {
    console.log('Test');
  }

  render() {
    const home = React.createElement('li', {
      className: 'navbar-item',
      id: 'home'
    }, 'Home');
    const contact = React.createElement('li', {
      className: 'navbar-item',
      id: 'about'
    }, 'Contact');
    const about = React.createElement('li', {
      className: 'navbar-item',
      id: 'contact',
      onClick: this.onItemClick
    }, 'About');

    return React.createElement('ul', {
      className: 'navbar'
    }, about, contact, home);
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Navbar, null, null),
  document.getElementById('navbar')
);
```

```html
<div id="navbar"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: The navbar now displays - but it automatically prints 'test' once and then button doesn't respond?

Comment: Thank you! I had to pass the class to ReactDOM render - u da best:)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
const about = React.createElement('li', {className: 'navbar-item', id: 'contact', onClick: this.onItemClick()}, 'About');
```

to

```
const about = React.createElement('li', {className: 'navbar-item', id: 'contact', onClick: this.onItemClick}, 'About');
```

Hope it helps